# Construct GitLab URL without slug

Tags: gitlab

Is there any way to build a GitLab URL for a milestone or project based on its `id` property instead of the slug?

#### Context:

I have an app that I use as a GitLab web hook, and from its front end would like to link back to GitLab. I'm keeping the project and milestone ids, as they are unique, but can't find a way to link back to them. Ideally something like: `http://gitlab.example.com/project/83/milestone/113` or even `http://gitlab.example.com/milestone/113` would work for me (even if they do a redirect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining `rake routes` and `config/routes.rb` tells me that such routes do not exist.

The only options I can see are:

- store just the slugs which are also unique. Your request and memory usage will be slightly larger, but it's worth it.
- make an extra API request to get the slugs. This requires 2 requests, so it is worse than having a larger request.

For new routes of form `/something` to be created in gitlab, `something` needs to be blacklisted at https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/199029b842de7c9d52b5c95bdc1cc897da8e5560/lib/gitlab/blacklist.rb, and interestingly `projects` is already blacklisted, but it is currently only used for project creation.

`milestones` however is not blacklisted: so a user could be called milestiones and that would generate ambiguity.

I would also take a close look at how GitHub organizes its API and paths, as it is likely to be optimal: is ID web access possible in GitHub?

Comment: I ended up adding an action to my controller that makes an API request and redirects to it. Not optimal, but I can later cache the results of that action and reduce API calls.